# event that the unzip process is finished

Tags: node.js

I use the following code which works

but I want to know when the API is done the extracting 
and finish the process, is there anyway to do it with this lib?
it based on yauzl

https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-zip

```
var extract = require('extract-zip')
extract(source, {dir: target}, function (err) {
 // extraction is complete. make sure to handle the err
})
```

I didnt find any event that the process done, but maybe I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

This module doesn't fire events. However, the callback function is called whenever the unzip process has finished (or an error occurred). This is the only way you are informed the process has finished. You can put your logic that needs to run after the process has finished there.

```
var extract = require('extract-zip')
extract(source, {dir: target}, function (err) {
  // extraction is complete. make sure to handle the err

  // If you are here the process of unzipping is done (or an error occurred)
})
```

If you really do want events, you can take a look at the underlying [`yauzl`](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) package as it uses events and streams extensively.